# Assigning javascript function with parameters to a variable gets instantly called

Tags: javascript, function, xmlhttprequest, anonymous-function

I'm trying to make a `xmlHttpRequest` before the page body loads. When trying to assign the `onreadystatechange` function, this one gets called *instantly*, thus returning `xmlHttp.readyState` **always to 0**.

I supose I'm making the call in a wrong way. How am I supposed to assign the function correctly?

```
//create xmlHttp object
function CreateXmlHttp() {
    try {
        var xmlHttp = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
    } catch(e) {
        try {
            xmlHttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        } catch(eo) {
            xmlHttp = null;
        }
    }
    if(!xmlHttp && typeof XMLHttpRequest != "undefined") {
        xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    return xmlHttp;
}

//request call
function post(url, func, XML) {
    var xmlHttp = CreateXmlHttp();
    //problem?
    xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = (function (xmlHttp, func) {
        if(xmlHttp.readyState == 4 && xmlHttp.status == 200) {
            func(xmlHttp.responseText);
        }
    })(xmlHttp, func);
    xmlHttp.open("POST", url, true);
    xmlHttp.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8');
    if(XML==null){
        XML = '';
    }
    xmlHttp.send(XML);
}

post('/json/checklogged', function (data) {
    var jsonData = eval("(" + data + ")"); //I know, this eval is dangerous
    if(jsonData.logged){
        var url = '${nextUrl}';
        post(url, function(data){
            document.open();
            document.write(data);
            document.close();
        });
        history.pushState({}, '', url);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if(xmlHttp.readyState == 4 && xmlHttp.status == 200) {
        func(xmlHttp.responseText);
    }
};
```

Don't execute the function at all. You're assigning a listener, i.e. creating (not executing) the function that *will* be called at the appropriate time.

The values inside the function will be in scope, so there's no need to pass them (which wouldn't help because the even delegation won't pass them anyway). It's called lexical scoping, or static scoping, or functional scoping (these terms aren't identical, but they're similar enough in this context).

Comment: @Nacho if it's a function, sure.

Comment: @davin Sorry, I wasn't clear, I mean if `func` will be in the scope even when `post` function finishes executing

Comment: @Nacho, yes, that's what I wrote. The environment model performs lookup within the context of the function definition. Since when you defined the function the variables are in scope, even after the outer function finishes executing they will remain in scope.

Answer (score 2):

It gets called instantly *because you're calling it* right after defining it:

```
xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = (function (xmlHttp, func) {
    ...
})(xmlHttp, func);
  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

You just need:

```
xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if(xmlHttp.readyState == 4 && xmlHttp.status == 200) {
        func(xmlHttp.responseText);
    }
};
```

This creates a closure around the `xmlHttp` and `func` objects, allowing you to use them in the function when onreadystate occurs, even after the `post` function has completed.

Comment: Thanks @Cameron! I can't accept more than one answer, so I do the fastest correct one.

Comment: @Nacho: Sure! Glad to have helped. Missed it by 28 seconds... ;-)

Answer (score 1):

`onreadystatechange` is a callback, and should not be self-executed. This should work:

```
xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if(xmlHttp.readyState == 4 && xmlHttp.status == 200) {
            func(xmlHttp.responseText);
        }
};
```

Comment: As-is that probably won't work, because you'll end up binding the two identifiers to undefined values (or whatever the event delegation passes, which I can't recall), you'll need to remove the parameters.